# Using adjectives after verbs?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, is-it-a-rule, linking-verbs

In a lot of sentences when speaking people use adjectives after verbs. In some examples it sounds right, however, and I was wondering if such uses were valid in formal writing.

The only example I can think of:

*"I'm hungry," she said, shocked.*

There are of course many cases in which I'm sure doing such a thing is incorrect:

*He ran slow*

*I ate quick*

But I ask about less blatantly incorrect examples such as the first one above.

Comment: There are over 450 hits here for a search on 'link verbs'. They are also known as 'linking verbs' (as their main function is to link a subject noun with a predicative adjective: John is cold / The rain became very heavy). Some similar verbs also carry semantic content (The rose blushed pink).

Comment: For "he ran slow", "he ate quick", slow and quick are acting like adverbs so they in a sense _are_ adverbs. It's non-standard usage (newspapers don't use it) but everyday people will use that a lot. As to "I am hungry", 'to be' takes adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist That’s not a duplicate—as stated in the question, this one is about sentences like “I’m hungry”. The question is based on a misunderstanding (or an imperfect understanding) of how the grammar works, but it’s not the same as the one in your link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjectives used with intransitive verbs in lieu of adverbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172624/adjectives-used-with-intransitive-verbs-in-lieu-of-adverbs)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I bet I can dig holes deeper than you can. I also bet that *dig* is transitive. :) Other examples are available upon demand, like typing comments faster.

Comment: Isn't 'deeper' indeterminate there? I bet I can dig holes deeper than you can: my brother runs the 'Big Pit', so I can dig holes in mile-deep tunnels.' // 'I bet I can dig holes deeper than you can: I've pinched my brother's shaft excavator.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ve never heard of a part-of-speech named “indeterminate”.  The verb *dig* can be used transitively or intransitively; in both cases, it readily accepts adverbs like *deep* and *deeper*. It can even be used bitransitively, such as when you dig Mary a hole deeper and faster than you dig Martha one.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to dig deeper. Perhaps not. 'Indeterminate':  uncertain in extent, amount, or nature [Collins]. What was that you were saying over at the 'Can one ever say for certain a word does not exist?' thread? Oh, you've deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

## Part One

*Hungry* is here used as an adjective. In the case of the verb *be*, it takes substantives (nouns or pronouns) or adjectives in its predicate complement, <sub><sup>**NOT**</sup></sub> adverbs.  You cannot say *“I am *soon.”* or *“I am *often.”* as complete sentences with a period/full stop following: both those are wrong.

This is because you cannot use an adverb to modify *be* any more than you can use an adverb to modify a pronoun.  Sure, you can use intensifiers, like saying *I really am*, but an intensifier isn’t exactly in the same class as an adverb. Plus there has been something left out at the end that’s to be understood as the target of the intensifier.

Sometimes people will get all tangled up about things like “I’m here” or “I’m there” or “I’m home”, but that all works differently: it’s not actually an adverb there. It’s some kind of substantive. Sometimes it’s more of a locative pronoun as with *here* or *there* or a temporal one like *now* or *then*.<sup>1</sup>

At other times it’s a normal noun used as an adverbial phrase in of itself, like *tomorrow* or *home*.  “Adverb” is something of a grab-bag category into which the weak-willed toss anything they don’t much know what to do with.

## Part Two

As for the other examples apart from *hungry*, those are <sub><sup>**NOT**</sup></sub> adjectives: they are clearly adverbs because they are modifying a verb. It doesn’t matter what they look like, and it doesn’t matter what one or another dictionary says that they “are”. All that matters is what they happen to be doing here and now, and here and now they are modifying verbs.

Remember this: Just as not all words that end in *-ly* are adverbs, not all adverbs end in *-ly*.

If one person runs <sub><sup>**FASTER**</sup></sub> than the second person, then the second person runs <sub><sup>**SLOWER**</sup></sub> the first.  If you dig down <sub><sup>**DEEPER**</sup></sub>, you will find that adverbs aren’t bound by any such *-ly* restrictions, be those in the positive degree, the comparative, or the superlative.

The <sub><sup>**SOONER**</sup></sub> you are brought to understand this, the <sub><sup>**SOUNDER**</sup></sub> you will sleep.

---

#### Footnotes

1. There’s a fancy word for these types of words — *deictic* — but it isn’t one they teach in grammar school and I don’t want to confuse anyone.

Comment: Another difference: adverbs _modify_ their verbs, which means they’re not in the predicate at all, unlike the noun phrases that constitute the predicates of linking verbs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You keep telegraphing my edits!!

Comment: I like this answer, but it seems that I see the problem differently. In the OP's first sentence, the word shocked seems to be a participle used as an adjective to describe the pronoun subject she. She did not "speak shocked". "Shocked, she spoke!" The rational quality of your answer and your overwhelmingly powerful reputation subdue my inclination to offer a competing answer.

Comment: @ScotM I never mentioned *shocked*.

Comment: Agreed, cheerfully. The OP's stated question: "But I ask about less blatantly incorrect examples such as the **first one above.**"

Comment: OOOOH, "I'm hungry!" So obviously correct, I missed it :) Still, have we answered your question, @Henry?

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen in military terminology, presumably originally from lists to make related items appear together when sorted alphabetically, e.g. 'meals, ready-to-eat' (MREs), 'airman, basic', 'sergeant major'.

See also this question: [when-can-an-adjective-be-postposed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91664/when-can-an-adjective-be-postposed)